# Changing value of one class object's variable in another class's method. (poker game)

Tags: c++

I am trying to change one class object's variable in another class's method:

```
class deck
{
    public:
    shuffleDeck();
    card pickCard();
    int topCard = 0;
    //protected:
};
card deck::pickCard()
{
        topCard++;
        return karta[topCard];
}

class board
{
    public:
    card karta[5] = {{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0},{0,0}};
    int jackpot = 0;
    int cardCount = 0;

    drawCard(deck);
};

board::drawCard(deck d)
{
    karta[cardCount] = d.pickCard();
    cardCount++;
}

deck d;
board b;
//
d.shuffleDeck();
b.drawCard(d);
b.drawCard(d);
b.drawCard(d);
b.drawCard(d);
showCard(b.karta[0]); //karta - card in polish
showCard(b.karta[1]);
showCard(b.karta[2]);
showCard(b.karta[3]);
cout<<"\n"<<b.cardCount;
cout<<"\n"<<d.topCard;
```

Those are parts of my code of console Texas Hold'em Poker. And this is the result of running the program:

```
8Karo 8Karo 8Karo 8Karo // 8Diamonds ...
4
0
Process returned 0 [...].
```

It clearly doesn't update the `topCard` value so I keep getting the same card on every card's slot on the board. I would like my program to call the `board::drawCard` function and then it would do another call `deck::pickCard();`

I know it should have been done by pointers but I just can't get it right.

Comment: `...::drawCard(deck& d)` add a `&` at the definition and implementation of `drawCard` function

Comment: Wow, that was suprisingly easy well I did a little mess in wrong class's function. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

```
  board::drawCard(deck &d)
```

The all important ampersand. You need a reference to the deck, not a copy of it.